# Skipping to Next item in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

When iterating through a dictionary, I want to skip an item if it has a particular key. I tried something like `mydict.next()`, but I got an error message `'dict' object has no attribute 'next'`

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if key == 'skipthis':
        mydict.next()
    # for others do some complicated process
```

I am using Python 2.7 if that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement):

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if key == 'skipthis':
        continue
```

Also see:

- [Are `break` and `continue` bad programming practices?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices)

Comment: Not a fan of this solution either 'continue' and 'break' are usually bad programming practices because they give a function/loop too many places to exit.

Comment: Well, in this particular case, when there is only one iteration to skip - I think it's pretty much ok to use `continue`. Check `UPD`, btw.

Comment: I agree that it works (and its certainly not the end of the world if you use it) but as a general principle it's best avoided. What's UPD?

Comment: @MikeVella Nothing wrong with using break/continue. There are many algorithms like searching for the index of some item in an array, or skipping over some unwanted item, that naturally call for break/continue. In what way is that bad practice? And what is your superior alternative?

Comment: @BasSwinckels There are many problems with break/continue, a method should have one point of entry and one point of exit, which makes it more readable. Usually when people use break/continue they are giving one unit of code too much work to do. My alternative is at the end of the post, dwerner has what is functionally the same solution.

Comment: Just had a look at the discussion on break and continue. There are a lot of people who are saying that break and continue are OK, they are definitely OK on the odd occasion  (usually for producing highly-optimized low-level code), but in almost all instances they are not, the boss of the OP in that question is right.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to call `mydict.iteritems().next()`, however you should just filter the list before iterating.

To filter your list, you could use a generator expression:

```
 r = ((k, v) for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if k != 'skipthis')
 for k,v in r:
      #do something complicated to filtered items
```

Because this is a generator expression, it has the property of only traversing the original dict once, leading to a boost in performance over other alternatives which iterate the dictionary, and optionally copy elements to a new one or delete existing elements from it. Generators can also be chained, which can be a powerful concept when iterating.

More info on generator expressions:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is this:

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if key != 'skipthis':
        # Do whatever
```

It does the same thing as skipping the key with `continue`.  The code under the if statement will only run if the key is not `'skipthis'`.

The advantage of this method is that it is cleaner and saves lines.  Also is a little better to read in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this, a lot of logic is now at a deeper level of nesting just to avoid executing it sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask the question *why* are you needing to do this? One unit of code should do one thing, so in this case the loop should have had the dict 'cleaned' before it reaches it.

Something along these lines:

```
def dict_cleaner(my_dict):
    #make a dict of stuff you want your loop to deal with
    return clean_dict

for key, value in dict_cleaner(mydict).iteritems():
#Do the stuff the loop actually does, no worrying about selecting items from it.
```

Comment: i am reading a complicated json data where i need to ignore certain inputs. point well taken

Comment: So you could have one method which has the job of cleaning that json data - in the future if you want to add/change the way you clean that json data you have a dedicated unit of code which *does only that* - it will be easier to maintain and for other people to understand.